# Converting from Option<String> to Option<&str>

Tags: rust

Very often I have obtained an `Option<String>` from a calculation, and I would like to either use this value or a default hardcoded value.

This would be trivial with an integer:

```
let opt: Option<i32> = Some(3);
let value = opt.unwrap_or(0); // 0 being the default
```

But with a `String` and a `&str`, the compiler complains about mismatched types:

```
let opt: Option<String> = Some("some value".to_owned());
let value = opt.unwrap_or("default string");
```

The exact error here is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:4:31
  |
4 |     let value = opt.unwrap_or("default string");
  |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |                               |
  |                               expected struct `std::string::String`, found reference
  |                               help: try using a conversion method: `"default string".to_string()`
  |
  = note: expected type `std::string::String`
             found type `&'static str`
```

One option is to convert the string slice into an owned String, as suggested by rustc:

```
let value = opt.unwrap_or("default string".to_string());
```

But this causes an allocation, which is undesirable when I want to immediately convert the result back to a string slice, as in this call to `Regex::new()`:

```
let rx: Regex = Regex::new(&opt.unwrap_or("default string".to_string()));
```

I would rather convert the `Option<String>` to an `Option<&str>` to avoid this allocation.

What is the idiomatic way to write this?

Comment: *which is undesirable* -> Is it really undesirable? Are you severely constrained by memory? Do you need to push every CPU cycle to the absolute limit? If either of these are true you are using the wrong language. `"default string".to_string())` is probably the correct solution here, because it keeps your code easy to understand, which is more important than saving 100 ns of CPU time, or 100 bytes of memory.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

As of Rust 1.40, the standard library has [`Option::as_deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref) to do this:

```
fn main() {
    let opt: Option<String> = Some("some value".to_owned());
    let value = opt.as_deref().unwrap_or("default string");
}
```

See also:

- [How can I iterate on an Option<Vec<_>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40907897/155423)

Comment: It works for me but I can't understand why my other version using `map` didn't work. I don't understand what happens to the first `Options<String>` and the copy that references it in the case of the `as_deref` variant of the code. Here's my working code using `as_deref`: `let device_id = UsbDeviceIdentifier::VidPidSn { vid: device.vendor_id, pid: device.product_id, sn: device.serial_number.as_deref().unwrap_or("") };` and my first try `let device_id = UsbDeviceIdentifier::VidPidSn { vid: device.vendor_id, pid: device.product_id, sn: device.serial_number.map(|s| s.as_str()).unwrap_or("") };`.

Comment: My error is `error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing function parameter \`s\``, `s.as_str() returns a value referencing data owned by the current function`. OK, but why does `as_deref` work, because it still creates a reference to the original `Option<String>` returned by `.serial_number`, so that still points to data owned by that `Option`!? Is the difference that `as_deref` does a transformation in place as opposed to doing it in the closure's body, where it is discarding the source of the slice it returns? If that's so, is there a way to fix that? Like return a copy of the str?

Comment: @Paul-SebastianManole please read [the existing answer that shows how to use `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31234028/155423); does that solve your issue?

Comment: Yeah, but I'm still puzzled.

Comment: @Paul-SebastianManole how about [Result of Option::map does not live long enough](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35249309/155423)

Comment: Interestingly, I can't get `as_deref()` to convert `Option<&String>` to `Option<&str>`. (The `Option<&String>` is obtained by a hash table lookup.) Of course, `.map(String::as_str)` works, but I wonder if there is a "standard" combinator to achieve the same. For example, `.copied().as_deref()` doesn't work either because `Option<&String>` is not `Copy`, and `.cloned().as_deref()` works, but at the cost of a cloning.

Answer (score 69):

You can use [`as_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) and [`map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map) to transform an `Option<String>` into an `Option<&str>`.

```
fn main() {
    let opt: Option<String> = Some("some value".to_owned());
    let value = opt.as_ref().map(|x| &**x).unwrap_or("default string");
}
```

First, `as_ref()` implicitly takes a reference on `opt`, giving an `&Option<String>` (because `as_ref()` takes `&self`, i.e. it receives a reference), and turns it into an `Option<&String>`. Then we use `map` to convert it to an `Option<&str>`. Here's what `&**x` does: the rightmost `*` (which is evaluated first) simply dereferences the `&String`, giving a `String` lvalue. Then, the leftmost `*` actually invokes the [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) trait, because `String` [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#implementations) `Deref<Target=str>`, giving us a `str` lvalue. Finally, the `&` takes the address of the `str` lvalue, giving us a `&str`.

You can simplify this a bit further by using [`map_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or) to combine `map` and `unwrap_or` in a single operation:

```
fn main() {
    let opt: Option<String> = Some("some value".to_owned());
    let value = opt.as_ref().map_or("default string", |x| &**x);
}
```

If `&**x` looks too magical to you, you can write `String::as_str` instead:

```
fn main() {
    let opt: Option<String> = Some("some value".to_owned());
    let value = opt.as_ref().map_or("default string", String::as_str);
}
```

or `String::as_ref` (from the [`AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) trait, which is in the [prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/prelude/v1/index.html)):

```
fn main() {
    let opt: Option<String> = Some("some value".to_owned());
    let value = opt.as_ref().map_or("default string", String::as_ref);
}
```

or `String::deref` (though you need to import the `Deref` trait too):

```
use std::ops::Deref;

fn main() {
    let opt: Option<String> = Some("some value".to_owned());
    let value = opt.as_ref().map_or("default string", String::deref);
}
```

For either of these to work, you need to keep an owner for the `Option<String>` as long as the `Option<&str>` or unwrapped `&str` needs to remain available. If that's too complicated, you could use [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html).

```
use std::borrow::Cow::{Borrowed, Owned};

fn main() {
    let opt: Option<String> = Some("some value".to_owned());
    let value = opt.map_or(Borrowed("default string"), |x| Owned(x));
}
```

Comment: bikesheddy comment: instead of `map(|x| &**x)` you could also do `map(String::as_ref)`.

Comment: This works nicely, although still a little verbose.  To clarify, the type of `opt.as_ref()` is `Option<&String>`, then `opt.as_ref().map(String::as_ref)` passes this `&String` to `String::as_ref`, which returns an `&str`.  Why can't the `&String` from `Option::as_ref` be coerced to an `&str`?

Comment: @thirtythreeforty `String::as_ref` returns an `&str`, not a `&&String` (see [here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/string/struct.String.html#method.as_ref))

Comment: @fjh I just realized that and edited :).  My coercion question remains.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty Your question is why deref coercions don't work for `Option<&String>` -> `Option<&str>` even though they work for `&String` -> `&str`? If so, I'm out of my depth, sorry.

Comment: Yes, that's my question.  I suppose it's a little more obvious that that doesn't work once you spell it out: there's no relationship between `Option<T>` and `Option<U>`, in general.

Comment: The `&**x` doesn't work for me in Rust 1.9. It says "error: type `str` cannot be dereferenced".

Comment: Can someone explain the `&**` part? How is `&**` equivalent to `as_ref` ?

Comment: @little-dude: In `&**`, the leftmost `*` actually invokes the `Deref` trait, because `String` implements `Deref<Target=str>`. `Deref::deref` and `AsRef::as_ref` both provide reference-to-reference conversions, and it happens that converting from `&String` to `&str` is available with both. You could use `map(String::deref)` instead of `map(String::as_ref)`, it would also be equivalent.

Comment: This was apparently a good answer back in 2015, but in 2023 it doesn't work anymore. Rust (version 1.71.1) now complains about lifetime parameter:
     = note: expected function signature `fn(std::string::String) -> _`
                found function signature `for<'a> fn(&'a std::string::String) -> _`

Answer (score 27):

A nicer way could be to implement this generically for `T: Deref`:

```
use std::ops::Deref;

trait OptionDeref<T: Deref> {
    fn as_deref(&self) -> Option<&T::Target>;
}

impl<T: Deref> OptionDeref<T> for Option<T> {
    fn as_deref(&self) -> Option<&T::Target> {
        self.as_ref().map(Deref::deref)
    }
}
```

which effectively generalizes `as_ref`.

Comment: This is a great utility function. I wish it was part of the standard library as a function on Option<T>!

Comment: Thanks! This works for me -- if I include this code, then `opt.as_deref()` is indeed an `Option<&str>`.

Answer (score 11):

Although I love Veedrac's answer (I used it), if you need it at just one point and you would like something that is expressive you can use `as_ref()`, `map` and `String::as_str` chain:

```
let opt: Option<String> = Some("some value".to_string());

assert_eq!(Some("some value"), opt.as_ref().map(String::as_str));
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way you can do it. Keep in mind that you *have* to keep the original `String` around, otherwise what would the `&str` be a slice into?

```
let opt = Some(String::from("test")); // kept around

let unwrapped: &str = match opt.as_ref() {
  Some(s) => s, // deref coercion
  None => "default",
};
```

[playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2b417ea38cfb1dfe915c&version=stable)

Comment: That didn't turn it into an Option<&str>.

Answer (score -2):

I found a way but not so readable... `.as_ref().map(|inner| inner.as_ref().map(|x| &**x))`

Comment: Why use that instead of the much simpler `as_deref()`?