# Why does Option<&String> not coerce to Option<&str>?

Tags: rust

I have an `Option<String>` and a function that takes an `Option<&str>`. I thought `Option::as_ref` would work, because usually `&String` converts automatically to `&str`, but not here. I get this error:

```
sandbox.rs:6:27: 6:37 error: mismatched types:
 expected `core::option::Option<&str>`,
    found `core::option::Option<&collections::string::String>`
(expected str,
    found struct `collections::string::String`) [E0308]
```

While [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31233938/155423) describes how to convert from one to the other, I'd still like to know why the `&String` isn't "coerced" (if that's the right term) into `&str` like it usually is.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that other question. It answers my "how" (and unfortunately, it looks like there isn't a built-in way to do it; you have to use `map` or something else to do the conversion manually). So yeah, I'm still left with the "why" question. I've edited the question to focus on that aspect of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your expectation is fair. If the compiler has magic to transform `&String` to `&str`, it should be able to also transform `Option<&String>` to `Option<&str>` or (for that matter) `AnyType<&String>` to `AnyType<&str>`.

But the compiler in this case has very little magic. Paradoxically coercions emerged from an attempt to *reduce* the magic in the compiler<sup>(*)</sup>. To understand this, you will have to understand the link between coercions and reborrows and follow me through a little excursus in Rust history.

A while back, in Rust you could relatively often see a construct like `&*x`: a "reborrow". For pointer types like `Box`, you wanted to be able to dereference them with `*` to get to the value inside. And if you needed a `&i32` but had a `x` that was a `Box<i32>`, you could reborrow it with `&*x`, which is really the composition of two operations, dereference the `Box` with `*` and take a new reference to its content with `&`. `Box` needed a lot of compiler magic to enable this.

So the thinking went: if we allowed anyone to decide what the `*` dereference does for their types, we would reduce the magic needed for custom pointers like `Box`, `Rc`, `Arc`, allowing new ones to be defined in libraries... And thus `Deref` was born.

But then, the Rust devs went one step further to reduce the unsightly reborrows. 
If you were passing a `&Box<i32>` to something expecting a `&i32` you might have needed to do this (which [still compiles](http://is.gd/eCeZW1) by the way):

```
fn main() {
    let a = &Box::new(2);
    test(&**a); // one * to dereference the Box, 
                // one * to dereference the &
                // reborrow with &
}

fn test(a: &i32) { println!("{}", *a) }
```

So (the good Rust devs went) why don't we make reborrowing automated and let people just write `test(a)`?

> When there is a type `T` (eg `Box<i32>`) that derefs to `U` (`i32`),
>   we'll let `&T` (`&Box<i32>`) "coerce" to `&U` (`&i32`).

This you may recognize as the current coercion rule. But all the magic the compiler performs is to try reborrowing for you by sprinkling `*`s (calling `deref`) as needed. More of a little parlor trick, actually.

Now, back to the `AnyType<&String>` to `AnyType<&str>` coercion. As we've seen, the compiler is much less magic than we were led to believe and dereferencing-reborrowing `&*AnyType<&String>` does not lead to the expected result. Even if you managed to implement `Deref` for `AnyType` and got `*AnyType<&String>` to deref to `AnyType<str>`, reborrowing the result would still yield `&AnyType<str>`, not `AnyType<&str>`.

So Rust's mechanism for coercion can't be used for this. You need to explicitly tell Rust how to take the `&String` out of `AnyType` and put a `&str` back in.

As one workaround for your specific scenario, if your function taking a `Option<&str>` is only one and under your control, you could generalize it to take a `Option<T>` where `T:AsRef<str>` instead, like this:

```
fn test<T: AsRef<str>>(o: Option<T>) {
    if let Some(s) = o { println!("{}", s.as_ref()) }
}
```

<sub>(*) the Rust devs are decidedly anti-magic, those muggles!</sub>

Answer (score 5):

There are two coersions in common use in Rust: auto-ref and auto-deref.

Auto-ref can only convert `T` to `&T` or `&mut T`, so isn't relevant here.

Auto-deref automatically calls `Deref::deref`. `Option<T>` doesn't implement `Deref`, so this cannot hold. `String`, however, does `deref` to `&str`, which is why you can see that coercion.

We know `Option` doesn't implement `Deref` since `Deref::deref` returns a pointer with the same lifetime as `&self`, and the lifetime requirements on pointers means that the pointer must thus live as long as `&self`, so with few exceptions the pointer must be to some pre-existing object rather than one created in the `deref` call.

This doesn't mean that the above is the *only* reason it doesn't implement `Deref`, although it is a sufficient one.

Answer (score 4):

The Rust language has defined a way to implicitly convert a `&T` into a `&U`, for specific pairs of `T` and `U`, through the `Deref` trait. It's important to understand that in some cases, `&U` is a constructed value. For example, neither `String` nor `&String` contain a `&str`, so the `deref()` method needs to create the `&str` manually.

However, the language has **not** defined a way to implicitly convert a `X<&T>` into a `X<&U>`. For that to work, the compiler would have to know a way to initialize a `X<&U>` given a `X<&T>` (and it's going to be different for different values of `X`). You can't simply take the binary representation of a `X<&T>` and reinterpret that as a `X<&U>`. In fact, an `Option<&String>` and an `Option<&str>` don't even have the same size! And even if the sizes matched, the pointers would usually not be the same.

In order to develop a generic solution to that problem, Rust would have to implement higher-kinded types (not available as of Rust 1.6). There could also be an *ad hoc* solution for that specific problem, but it would become redundant when HKT are implemented.

Comment: I don't really get what HKTs would be needed for. Surely one would just need, say, `DerefValue` which returned `DerefValue::Target` directly, rather than as a reference. HKTs would only be needed if you wanted to restrict the types of dereferences possible, which seems wholly anathema to the idea of the generalization suggested.

Comment: I imagined a trait `Convert` you could implement on a type constructor such as `Option`, providing a single method `convert` which took two generic parameters, `T` and `U`, such that its argument would be a `Self<&T>` and its result would be a `Self<&U>` where `T: Deref<Target=U>`.

Comment: Yeah, but what does that gain you? One can't convert an `Option<Option<T>>` to an `Option<Option<&T>>`, nor a `BitVec` to a `BitSlice` by such a manner, but it does allow implementing it for `Vec`, despite that probably being a bad idea. I don't really get what you gain for forcing the transformation to be this particular type function if you're not restricting what the function can actually do (as `Deref` does).

Comment: Well, I think that is good motivation for not supporting such implicit conversions. :)