# Result of Option::map does not live long enough

Tags: rust, lifetime

I expected the two functions below to be equivalent. However the first one does not compile.

```
pub fn does_not_work<I: IntoIterator>(values: I)
where
    I::Item: AsRef<str>,
{
    if let Some(value) = values.into_iter().nth(0).map(|item| item.as_ref()) {
        if value == "first" {
            println!("This should print");
        }
    }
}

pub fn does_work<I: IntoIterator>(values: I)
where
    I::Item: AsRef<str>,
{
    if let Some(value) = values.into_iter().nth(0) {
        if value.as_ref() == "first" {
            println!("This should print");
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    does_work(&["first"]);
}
```

The compile error is:

```
error[E0597]: `item` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:5:63
  |
5 |     if let Some(value) = values.into_iter().nth(0).map(|item| item.as_ref()) {
  |                                                               ^^^^        - `item` dropped here while still borrowed
  |                                                               |
  |                                                               borrowed value does not live long enough
...
9 |     }
  |     - borrowed value needs to live until here
```

The code is altered so as to be less verbose than the actual context it comes from and to more clearly illustrate the point. To clarify why I want to use the first approach, I use `value` many more times in my actual code and I don't want to have every single one of them followed by a `.as_ref()`.

Is there a way to make this work or is `Option::map` not a good choice for this situation? Is there another concise way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a new iterator, old values are not available anymore. But you need the old value to exist in order to return `Some(value)`. In your case, you're passing a `&[&'static str]` to the function, so it's guaranteed to stay around long enough, but according to the types you could just as well pass `&[String]`.

In that case, the original `String` could be freed and you'd be left with a dangling pointer. By not calling `.as_ref()`, you guarantee that the original value will be available in the `Some(value)`.

If you just want to skip multiple `.as_ref()` calls you can instead do:

```
pub fn does_work<I: IntoIterator>(values: I)
where
    I::Item: AsRef<str>,
{
    if let Some(value) = values.into_iter().next() {
        let s = value.as_ref();
        if s == "first" {
            println!("This should print");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how calling `.as_ref()` one line later is safe while calling it in the if let is not.

Comment: It's about which block it's called in, rather than line. In your `does_not_work` example `item` does not exist anymore after the `map`, so returning any pointer to previous value from it is not possible. In both your second example and in my answer, `value` and `item` are the same. And `s` is just the converted `value` - they both exist in the same block (until the end of `if`).

Answer (score 2):

That's because `map` takes ownership of the parameter `item`, so it will be destroyed after it returns. This makes the result reference invalid.

You should apply `Option::as_ref` to transform `Option<T>` into `Option<&T>` before using `map`, like this:

```
pub fn does_not_work<I: IntoIterator>(values: I)
where
    I::Item: AsRef<str>,
{
    if let Some(value) = values.into_iter().next().as_ref().map(|item| item.as_ref()) {
        if value == "first" {
            println!("This should print");
        }
    }
}
```