# How can I iterate on an Option<Vec<_>>?

Tags: rust

I am trying to iterate on on `Option<Vec<>>`.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Person {
    pub name: Option<String>,
    pub age: Option<u64>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Foo {
    pub people: Option<Vec<Person>>,
}
```

Naively I am using

```
for i in foo.people.iter() {
    println!("{:?}", i);
}
```

Instead of iterating over all the elements of the `Vec`, I am actually displaying the whole `Vec`. It is like I am iterating over the only reference of the `Option`.

Using the following, I am iterating over the `Vec` content:

```
for i in foo.people.iter() {
    for j in i.iter() {
        println!("{:?}", j);
    }
}
```

I am not sure this is the most pleasant syntax, I believe you should unwrap the `Option` first to actually iterate on the collection.

Then I don't see where you can actually use `Option::iter`, if you always have a single reference.

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f0cba97a3915f2cf8686794a1a41627e&version=stable&backtrace=0) is the link to the playground.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I don't understand in which case you should use Option<>.iter(), I got maybe wrongly the feeling that it will always return a single item.

Comment: @XavierT. `Option::iter` is designed for cases where you want to treat the option as a zero-or-one-element container. It doesn't seem very useful to me either, but that's the idea.

Comment: @user4815162342 `let foo: Vec<Option<T> = vec![]; let bar: Vec<T> = foo.into_iter().flat_map(|x| x).collect();`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Option` has an [`iter` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.iter) that "iterates over the possibly contained value", i.e. provides either the single value in the `Option` (if option is `Some`), or no values at all (if the option is `None`). As such it is useful if you want to treat the option as a container where `None` means the container is empty and `Some` means it contains a single element.

To iterate over the underlying element's values, you need to switch from `foo.people.iter()` to either `foo.people.unwrap().iter()` or `foo.people.unwrap_or_else(Vec::new).iter()`, depending on whether you want the program to panic or to not iterate when encountering `None` people.

Compilable example [in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=ca0da6a1d400db8e9fc58a0d1e27eb3c).

Comment: instead of `unwrap` one could also simply wrap `if let Some(ref v) = foo.people {}` around the iteration

Comment: @ker That's another option (no pun intended), but it does require an additional indentation level around the loop. `unwrap()` is still useful when the code actually expects the option to be non-`None` and wants to assert that.

Comment: If I always wanted to iterate over the people I would probably do `foo.people.iter().flat_map(|v|v.iter())`, `None` would give an empty iterator while otherwise we would give all the elements of the vector.

Comment: @Lukazoid no need for `v.iter()`; just `v` will work.

Comment: @Shepmaster I didn't spot that `flat_map` handles `IntoIterator`, even better then.

Comment: @Lukazoid You should answer that. `foo.people.iter().flat_map(identity)` is a better way to iterate IMO.

Comment: @Boiethios You mean the `identity` function added 2 years after my comment? Edit: Oh you mean add as an additional answer? Sorry I misunderstood

Comment: @Lukazoid I meant the solution, whatever if you type `|v| v` or `identity`: that's still beter than an `unwrap` or an `unwrap_or_else(Vec::new)`.

Comment: @Boiethios It's not (stylistically) better than an `unwrap` because it has different behavior. I argue that it's not better than `unwrap_or_else` either because `unwrap_or_else` makes it clearer what's going on without relying on `Option` acting like a container. (Also, `Vec::new()` is guaranteed not to allocate, so there should be no performance lost in the `None` case.) Judging by the generated assembly ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=0cb79cdfaad105f1ea06e89684c33231)), the `unwrap_or_else` version is more efficient as well.

Answer (score 25):

As mentioned in comments to another answer, I would use the following:

```rust
// Either one works
foo.people.iter().flatten()
foo.people.iter().flat_map(identity)
```

The `iter` method on `Option<T>` will return an iterator of one or zero elements.

[`flatten`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flatten) takes each element (in this case `&Vec<Person>`) and flattens their nested elements.

This is the same as doing [`flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map) with [`identity`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/fn.identity.html), which takes each element (in this case `&Vec<Person>`) and flattens their nested elements.

Both paths result in an `Iterator<Item = &Person>`.

Comment: Note if `foo.people` is a `Option` over a stacked borrow (aka `foo.people: Option<&&Vec<i32>>` , then the reference should be *unstacked* using `.cloned()`. e.g. `foo.people.cloned().iter().flatten()`

Comment: @Ben Do you know another way to do this in the case of a "stacked borrow"? I'd like to iterate over a `Option<&HashMap<...,...>>` and treat `None` as empty HashMap without having to copy the content.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Option::as_deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref) and [`Option::unwrap_or_default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_default):

```
for i in foo.people.as_deref().unwrap_or_default() {
    println!("{:?}", i);
}
```

`Option::as_deref` converts `&Option<Vec<T>>` into `Option<&[T]>`, then `unwrap_or_default` returns that `&[T]` or the default (an empty slice). You can then iterate on that directly.

See also:

- [Converting from Option<String> to Option<&str>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31233938/155423)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need an actual value with an `IntoIterator` implementation, you can just use an explicit `if let` instead:

```rust
if let Some(x) = foo.people {
    for i in x {
        // work with i here
    }
}
```