# How to iterate over a borrowed Option<Vec<_>> treating None as an empty iterator?

Tags: vector, rust, iterator, option-type

I have a struct and receive a reference to it in a function. I'd like to iterate over the field and if it is is `None` it should behave as if the `Vec` is empty. The best I can think of is

```
struct A {
    m: Option<Vec<_>>,
}

fn example(a: &A) {
    let v = vec![];
    a.m.as_ref().unwrap_or_else(|| &v).iter()
}
```

I don't like declaring an outside vector just to have it exist outside of `unwrap_or_else`.

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: If you want it to not iterate at all when it's `None`, consider a simple `if let Some(x) = checks { /* iterate over x */ }`, or consider the answers on this thread: [Iterator on Option<Vec<>>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40907897/5923139)

Comment: Apologies for introducing additional noise in the code. I've added an explanation that if the Option is None I want to pretend as if the Vec is empty meaning the iter wouldn't iterate over any elements. @Aplet123 answered my question

Comment: [alternative solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ea41586896892f1bbc781276db7dc604)

Comment: @Aplet123 I think it's reasonable to explicitly add your `if let` answer to the question you linked.