# Why does Option<String>.as_ref() not deref to Option<&str>?

Tags: string, rust, option-type

I expect the same result for both of these code samples:

```
let maybe_string = Some(String::from("foo"));
let string = if let Some(ref value) = maybe_string { value } else { "none" };
```

```
let maybe_string = Some(String::from("foo"));
let string = maybe_string.as_ref().unwrap_or("none");
```

The second sample gives me an error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:3:50
  |
3 |     let string = maybe_string.as_ref().unwrap_or("none");
  |                                                  ^^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found str
  |
  = note: expected type `&std::string::String`
             found type `&'static str`
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because that's how [`Option::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) is defined:

```
impl<T> Option<T> {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> Option<&T>
}
```

Since you have an `Option<String>`, then the resulting type *must* be `Option<&String>`.

Instead, you can add in [`String::as_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_str%60):

```
maybe_string.as_ref().map(String::as_str).unwrap_or("none");
```

Or the shorter:

```
maybe_string.as_ref().map_or("none", String::as_str);
```

As of Rust 1.40, you can also use [`Option::as_deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref).

```
maybe_string.as_deref().unwrap_or("none");
```

See also:

- [Converting from Option<String> to Option<&str>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31233938/155423)

Comment: Related discussion on ways of going from `Option<String>` to `Option<&str>` is occurring in [a proposed RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1792).