# Matching on an enum reference and returning a string results in "match arms have incompatible types"

Tags: rust

How do I `match` on an enum reference? I am using a dependency that returns a reference to an enum and I need to read the value the enum contains. In the following example, the thing I care about is assigning `final_val` with `x`:

```
fn main() {
    let test_string = String::from("test");
    let option: std::option::Option<String> = Some(test_string);
    let ref_option = &option;

    let final_val = match ref_option {
        Some(x) => x,
        _ => String::from("not Set"),
    };

    println!("{:?}", final_val);
}
```

If I follow what the compiler suggests and add a `&` to the type `Some` and `ref x`:

```
fn main() {
    let test_string = String::from("test");
    let option: std::option::Option<String> = Some(test_string);
    let ref_option = &option;

    let final_val = match ref_option {
        &Some(ref x) => x,
        _ => String::from("not Set"),
    };

    println!("{:?}", final_val);
}
```

I get the following error, which I don't know how to resolve:

```
error[E0308]: match arms have incompatible types
  --> src\main.rs:6:21
   |
6  |       let final_val = match ref_option
   |  _____________________^
7  | |     {
8  | |         &Some(ref x) => x,
9  | |         _ => String::from("not Set" ),
   | |              ------------------------ match arm with an incompatible type

10 | |     };
   | |_____^ expected reference, found struct `std::string::String`
   |
   = note: expected type `&std::string::String`
              found type `std::string::String`
```

Comment: Do you want the type of `final_val` to be a string, or a reference to a string? You can't do both.

Comment: I would like it to be a string

Comment: In case the enum is *actually* an `&Option<String>`, then check out [Why does Option<String>.as_ref() not deref to Option<&str>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44163624/155423) and [Converting from Option<String> to Option<&str>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31233938/155423). TL;DR: `ref_option.as_ref().map_or("not Set", String::as_str)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does not work. On the first arm you return `&String`, in the second arm you return `String`.

It will work if you clone `x`, but it's unclear what you really want.

```
let final_val = match ref_option {
    &Some(ref x) => x.clone(),
    _ => String::from("not Set"),
};
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=52381015096810d9a4628f1dabbd2396&version=stable)

Edit:

> I would like it to be a string

Then the mentioned solution is the way to go. However, if you don't really need a `String`, you should go with [tafia's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49446964/155423):

```
let final_val = match *ref_option {
    Some(ref x) => x,
    _ => "not Set",
};
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2042df2b009f8909ea5331af03e09793&version=stable)

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 issues

1. You must either match on `*ref_option` or have `&Some(...)` and `&None` in the branches. Matching on `*ref_option` is more idiomatic.
2. Once matched, you use a `ref x` which is a reference to the `String` (equivalent to a `&String`). So either you `clone` it, [as suggested by Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49441819/155423) or you return a `&String` (dereferenced to a `&str`) in both branches.

To conclude, you can:

```
let final_val = match *ref_option {
    Some(ref x) => x,
    _ => "not Set",
};
```