# How can I pattern match against an Option<String>?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I can straight-forwardly match a `String` in Rust:

```
let a = "hello".to_string();

match &a[..] {
    "hello" => {
        println!("Matches hello");
    }
    _ => panic!(),
}
```

If I have an option type, it fails:

```
match Some(a) {
    Some("hello") => {
        println!("Matches some hello");
    }
    _ => panic!(),
}
```

because the types don't match:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:5:14
  |
5 |         Some("hello") => {
  |              ^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found reference
  |
  = note: expected type `std::string::String`
             found type `&'static str`
```

I can't do the `[..]` trick because we have an `Option`. The best that
I have come up with so far is:

```
match Some(a) {
    Some(b) => match (&b[..]) {
        "hello" => {
            println!("Matches some, some hello");
        }
        _ => panic!(),
    },
    None => panic!(),
}
```

which works but is terrible for its verbosity.

In this case, my code is just an example. I do not control the creation of either the `String` or the `Some(String)` — so I can't change this type in reality as I could do in my example.

Any other options?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's a known limitation of Rust's patterns.

Method calls (including internal methods for operators like `==`) automatically call `.deref()` as needed, so `String` gets automagically turned into `&str` for comparisons with literals.

On the other hand, the patterns are quite literal in their comparisons, and find that `String` and `&str` are different.

There are two solutions:

1. Change `Option<String>` to `Option<&str>` before matching on it: `Some(a).as_deref()`. The `as_deref()` is a combo of `as_ref()` that makes `Option<&String>` (preventing move), and `deref()`/`as_str()` then unambiguously references it as a `&str`.
2. Use match guard: `match Some(a) { Some(ref s) if s == "hello" => … }`. `Some(ref s)` matches any `String`, and captures it as `s: &String`, which you can then compare in the `if` guard which does the usual flexible coercions to make it work.

See also:

- [Converting from Option<String> to Option<&str>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31233938/155423)

Comment: This is good -- I prefer 1 because it's less verbose as I want to match more than one string. But, I find it confusing. Why can we create an iterator over a single value, on `Option`? And why can we match a single value on the return of `map` ? Should this not be a `Iterator` type?

Comment: Here `.map()` is not an iterator at all. It's a helper method on `Option` that allows you to change it if it's `Some` and do nothing if it's `None`.

Comment: Ah, excuse my ignorance. Totally misunderstood the rust-doc for Option. Yes, you are right -- "map" == map one option to another, just with the same name as a collection.

Comment: An alternative to point 1 could be `Some(a).as_deref()`

Answer (score 34):

As of Rust 1.40, you can now call `as_deref` on `Option<String>` to convert it to `Option<&str>` and then match on it:

```rust
match args.nth(1).as_deref() {
    Some("help") => {}
    Some(s) => {}
    None => {}
}
```

I found this because it is [one of the clippy lints](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#option_as_ref_deref).

Answer (score 5):

[Look at this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7a1d609ec43797e3fe7591feb5f8c0f9&version=stable).

You cannot match on `std::String`, as you've found, only on `&str`. Nested pattern matches work, so if you can match on `&str`, you can match on `Option<&str>`, but still not on `Option<String>`.

In the working example, you turned the `std::String` into a `&str` by doing `&a[..]`. If you want to match on a `Option<String>`, you have to do the same thing.

One way is to use nested matches:

```
match a {
    Some(ref s) => match &s[..] {
        "hello" => /* ... */,
        _ => /* ... */,
    },
    _ => /* ... */,
}
```

But then you have to duplicate the "otherwise" code if it's the same, and it's generally not as nice.

Instead, you can turn the `Option<String>` into an `Option<&str>` and match on this, using the `map` function. However, `map` consumes the value it is called on, moving it into the mapping function. This is a problem because you want to reference the string, and you can't do that if you have moved it into the mapping function. You first need to turn the `Option<String>` into a `Option<&String>` and map on that.

Thus you end up with `a.as_ref().map(|s| /* s is type &String */ &s[..])`. You can then match on that.

```
match os.as_ref().map(|s| &s[..]) {
    Some("hello") => println!("It's 'hello'"),
    // Leave out this branch if you want to treat other strings and None the same.
    Some(_) => println!("It's some other string"),
    _ => println!("It's nothing"),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, you can use `unwrap_or` to replace `Option::None` with a predefined `&str` you don't want to handle in any special way.

I used this to handle user inputs:

```
let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

match args.get(1).unwrap_or(&format!("_")).as_str() {
    "new" => {
        print!("new");
    }
    _ => {
        print!("unknown string");
    }
};
```

Or to match your code:

```
let option = Some("hello");

match option.unwrap_or(&format!("unhandled string").as_str()) {
    "hello" => {
        println!("hello");
    }
    _ => {
        println!("unknown string");
    }
};
```

Comment: You can avoid a temporary allocation by changing order of dereferecing/unwrapping: `option.as_deref().unwrap_or("unhandled string")`. Also `String::from("_")` generates way less code than the dynamic formatting machinery.