# How can I borrow the item in an Option or create a new item when it's None?

Tags: rust, option-type, borrow-checker, borrowing

When I have an `Option` and want a reference to what's inside or create something if it's a `None` I get an error.

Example Code:

```
fn main() {
    let my_opt: Option<String> = None;

    let ref_to_thing = match my_opt {
        Some(ref t) => t,
        None => &"new thing created".to_owned(),
    };

    println!("{:?}", ref_to_thing);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b9ab48c1dd204dd005d61f5ee6527ede&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Error:

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:6:18
   |
6  |         None => &"new thing created".to_owned(),
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-
   |                  |                            |
   |                  |                            temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
   |                  temporary value does not live long enough
...
10 | }
   | - temporary value needs to live until here
```

Basically the created value doesn't live long enough. What is the best way to get a reference to the value in a `Some` or create a value if it's a `None` and use the reference?

Comment: See also [Converting from Option<String> to Option<&str>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31233938/155423).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also just write:

```
None => "new thing created"
```

With this adjustment your initial variant of the code will compile without the need of an extra variable binding.

An alternative could also be:

```
let ref_to_thing = my_opt.unwrap_or("new thing created".to_string());
```

Comment: Well my attempt to simplify my problem to an example failed. I wasn't using &str or String. In my original problem it was a &DatabaseConnection which wasn't easily solved that way as well as having the option be part of &mut of a struct which made things interesting. But yes for my example you are correct.

Comment: Going to mark this as the correct answer as in my lame example it is.

Comment: Worth noting that `unwrap_or` takes ownership of the Option which is not always possible. Like if the Option is owned by a struct and you only have an `&mut` of the struct. [unwrap_or](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or)

Answer (score 4):

The only way I've found is to create a "dummy variable" to hold the created item and give it a lifetime:

```
fn main() {
    let my_opt: Option<String> = None;

    let value_holder;
    let ref_to_thing = match my_opt {
        Some(ref t) => t,
        None => {
            value_holder = "new thing created".to_owned();
            &value_holder
        }
    };

    println!("{:?}", ref_to_thing);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6fd697c4f6321be961a963b518daa794&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind mutating your `Option` in place, you can use [`Option::method.get_or_insert_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.get_or_insert_with):

```
fn main() {
    let mut my_opt: Option<String> = None;

    let ref_to_thing = my_opt.get_or_insert_with(|| "new thing created".to_owned());

    println!("{:?}", ref_to_thing);
}
```

Comment: Interesting, learned something new. For my original problem that wouldn't work, but for the example I suppose it could. Thanks!