# Why does comparing Option<String> with constant Option<&str> need explicit type conversion?

Tags: rust

The following [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=33a5097941119d5b203bb34d6e3dd5c9) fails:

```rust
let s = Some("abc".to_string());    
let _ = s.as_ref() == Some("abc"); // fails
```

with the following error:

```
4 |     let _ = s.as_ref() == Some("abc"); // fails
  |                           ---- ^^^^^ expected `&String`, found `&str`
```

I would've thought this conversion happens implicitly per [Deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#more-on-deref-coercion) which says that:

> If T implements Deref<Target = U>, and x is a value of type T, then ...  **Values of type &T are coerced to values of type &U**

So, `&String` should've been implicitly converted to `&str` per `String`'s Deref implementations.

Instead, I have to explicitly convert it as follows:

```rust
    let _ = s.as_ref().map(|x| x.as_str()) == Some("abc"); // works
```

Why is the explicit conversion necessary?

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with `Deref`, because this compiles just fine: `let _ = s.as_ref() == Some(&"abc".to_string());`

Comment: Use `let _ = s.as_deref() == Some("abc");` that is, https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting from Option<String> to Option<&str>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233938/converting-from-optionstring-to-optionstr)

Comment: @BiagioF I know there are multiple ways of solving this. I'm asking _why_ it's necessary at all.

Comment: `Option` cannot be coerced, so anything inside it is also ineligible for coercion. Coercion can only happen for certain types, usually `&`, `&mut`, and `Box`.

Comment: Also deref doesn't happen for the binary operators. The only reason you can do `String == &str` is that there is an explicit impl for that: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-PartialEq%3CString%3E-for-%26'a+str.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right

> Values of type &T are coerced to values of type &U

but of the two types involved

- `Option<&String>`
- `Option<&str>`

neither does `Option<&String>: Deref<Target = Option<&str>>` nor `Option<&str>: Deref<Target = Option<&String>>` hold.

In fact `Option` doesn't implemnt `Deref` at all.

So even if you write it as

```rust
s.as_ref().eq(&Some("abc"))
// or
Some("abc").eq(&s.as_ref())
```

which would allow coercion as opposed to the operator syntax, it won't be coerced since it doesn't follow any of the requirements for coercion.

Answer (score 1):

While `String` implements `PartialEq` [for a variety of different types,](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-PartialEq%3C%26%27a+str%3E-for-String) `Option<T>` [only implements `PartialEq<Option<T>>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#impl-PartialEq%3COption%3CT%3E%3E-for-Option%3CT%3E), and so the inner types must match exactly.

The biggest reason why there is only one implementations is due to the limitations of blanket trait implementations - an implementation of `PartialEq<&T> for Option<T>` would conflict with the existing declaration, which Rust prevents.

`Deref` is irrelevant here since you're not comparing references directly.

Comment: I'm curious though, is that possible to have `impl<T, U> PartialEq<Option<U>> for Option<T> where T: PartialEq<U>` (i.e. require only that inner types are comparable, not that they're the same)? Will this conflict with something?