Why does `unwrap_or` not compile where `if let` does?
I'm trying to understand Rust better, but it continues to confuse me. In this case I expected two blocks of code to be equivalent, but one compiles where the other does not.
This one compiles:
if let Some(thing) = thing_list.get(*index) {
    text.push_str(thing);
} else {
    text.push_str(other);
}

This one wont compile:
text.push_str(
    thing_list.get(*index).unwrap_or(other)
);

but I thought they would do the exact same thing. Here is the error I get from the second block:

arguments to the unwrap_or method are incorrect: expected &String, found &&str

Note that the context of both blocks of code is the same:

thing_list is of type &Vec<String>
index is of type &usize
text is of type String
other is of type &&str

I just found out the second block works if I do unwrap_or(&other.to_string())
Is it just the case that some automatic conversion can be done in the first block but not the second?

Very relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233938/converting-from-optionstring-to-optionstr

text.push_str requires &str. &String and &&str can both be coerced to &str, but &&str cannot be coerced to &String.
thing_list.get(*index) returns &String, and so does the following unwrap_or. That's why it cannot accept &&str. If you want do the same thing as the if let block, you can use
thing_list.get(*index).map(|s| s.as_str()).unwrap_or(other)

Calling as_str converts &String to &str and &&str can also be coerced to that.

Your map() is called as_deref().
